# Does an android app show all permission it can access?

Tags: permissions

Generally when you install an application, a list of permission is shown what thing that app can access in your phone. But do they show all the permissions? The app developer don't want you to know  some things their app can access like an app can read your contents in SD card but what if it can also read your device ID and MAC Address, will this be written in the list of permissions specially when the developers intentionally want to hide this? Does google allow such apps on play store which hide some app permissions?

Comment: Few OEM company have given that feature in few devices.

Comment: Do you meam the feature to hide permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently picked up Android development myself so I can tell you what I know.

Generally when an app needs access to features it has to declare it in `AndroidManifest.xml`, or else the system throws exception when the app tries to access the feature. Also, even if the app declares permissions in detail (e.g. it wants to send/receive SMS), Android and Google Play will show the permission groups those permissions belong to (e.g. "phone calls and messaging", or something like that). In that sense when you look at the permission list displayed in Google Play or when installing you gain yourself a knowledge of the *maximum* this app is capable of doing.

There can be some exceptions, for example a feature not yet natively implemented in Android but by certain manufacturers, but as Android version grows later, these permissions should automatically get added to the apps requirement, even if the app does not explicitly state it. You still get the *maximum* knowledge.

If any veteran developer spot mistakes in what I said, please do point out, as I'm only a beginner in this field.

Comment: Can a developer secretly add a permission in its updates without letting that permission to be displayed to user?

Comment: Requesting internet access no longer requires the user to acknowledge the added permission (if the developer added it in an update). Otherwise adding a permission requires confirmation by the user.
However, it is possible to programmatically request extra permissions. This will cause a popup that the user has to confirm in order to grant the permission. However, there are proof of concept "games"/exploits that use clickjacking to get the user to click Android buttons that are cleverly hidden below an overlay created by the malicious app.

Comment: @gertmenkel Android protects the user against clickjacking/tapjacking (unless some Xposed module is installed). I don't know how secure it is but it generally always works.

Comment: @GiantTree more recent versions of android are better protected better against this. However, the problem with Android security is that there are very few devices that still get updates after two years, or even run the latest android version at launch date. For example, according to Google almost 85% of all android devices run Android 5 or lower. Versions up until android 5 are vulnerable to clickjacking by abusing the accessibility framework. Newer versions are still vulnerable if a user (accidentally) gives the app accessibility permissions, which is harder to do now. It's still very viable.

Comment: @gertmenkel good point, I never use an "old" version of Android because I usually install custom ROMs but your point is very important. I hope one day Google will force manufacturers to push security updates for 2 years or so.

Comment: @gertmenkel Safe permissions are automatically granted without notifying the user as I know, so is it that "internet" is now considered safe? Also, good point on clickbaiting, even people here could fall victim for that.

Comment: I was thinking about to install xposed framework and its modules but by reading your all comments it sounds that they are malicious and they will have full access to my phone.

Comment: @user334283 By using Xposed modules and modding the phone in general you're trusting your phone with the developers. That's why we are told to only use trusted popular modules and stay away from one-click root apps.

Comment: I want to use Xprivacy to block unnecessary app permissions and for that it requires xposed framework

Comment: @user334283 I've been using that too and it works mighty fine for its purpose (I use it to prevent internet connection for certain apps). If you don't trust the dev for that then there's nothing else you can do.